# C# Enum Flags -= allowed, but += requires cast to int

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I got a quick question for you; Why is -= allowed for enums, but += requires an explicit cast to int?

```
EnumTest value = EnumTest.Two;
value += EnumTest.One; // Compile error
value += (int)EnumTest.One; // Valid operation
value -= EnumTest.One; // Valid operation

[Flags]
public enum EnumTest
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

Comment: You missed an important information... which language is it?

Comment: oops, sorry. this is for C#

Comment: I did vote to close, but I think the reason that subtraction is allowed but addition is not relates to making flag setting/unsetting operations look simple. Setting a flag can be done with just `|`. Unsetting a flag (without `-` working) requires `&` with the inverse of the flag bit to unset.

Comment: thanks everyone. Yeah it looks like a duplicate, I'm closing this

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, not sure because using `-`/`+` depends on the current value, unlike `|`/`&`, so it is quite risky